How to change VS Code extension keybindings programmatically?
I'm developing an extension on VS Code with a default keybindings declared in package.json file. I want to add a feature that allows user to override the keybindings on each project.
Currently, my extension finds in the root of the opened project a json file (extra-config.json) to extract the key combination that user want to override with. I already manage to make my extension to call the overriding function when VS Code is opened or when the file extra-config.json is saved, but I don't know what to do next to override the current keybindings.
Is what I'm seeking possible? If it is, please give me an example!
Thank you!
